# Understanding the switch statement and pointers in Go

Tags: go

I can't figure out why this Go code with pointers and using the switch statement prints out "a":

```
import "fmt"

func main() {
    var a, b int
    var c = &b
    switch *c {
    case a:
        fmt.Println("a")
    case b:
        fmt.Println("b")
    default:
        fmt.Println("c")
    }
}
```

Any hints to this?

Comment: The value of b (which is 0 in this case) is compared. The first case that matches is `a`.

Comment: The fact that c is a pointer is totally irrelevant for the question. Your code is nonsensical and this might have lead to the confusion.

Comment: May be you wanted to compare the address ? If it’s the case this is what you should have done  “switch c ... and case &a: ...”: see: https://play.golang.org/p/X5RspXHLs9Q.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`a` and `b` are both zero (the zero value for integers).

Initializing `c = &b` means that `c` is a `*int` pointing to `b`.

Moving on to the switch statement, we are checking the value of `*c` which dereferences `c` and is the value of `b`, which is `0`.

Since `a` is also zero, the [first case matches](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Switch_statements).

You can swap the `case a` and `case b` statements and put `b` first. In that case, it will print `b` since it is now the first matching case:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    var a, b int
    var c = &b

    switch *c {
    case b:
        fmt.Println("b")
    case a:
        fmt.Println("a")
    default:
        fmt.Println("c")
    }
}
```